# Puzzle: Trail a shape without overlapping lines

Tags: geometry, puzzle

Here is a challenge a friend of mine came up with:

[image: Shape]

> Use a pen and recreate this shape. You can only draw 3 lines that can start
>   anywhere and end anywhere. The lines cannot overlap at one point.

---

To be honest, I can't figure it out. The problem is, that there are 3 lines connected to each point.

Neither I nor my friend, the creator of the challenge, came up with a solution yet. And we weren't able to prove it's impossible either.

*Can someone find the solution of this puzzle? Or can you prove that it is impossible to solve this puzzle?*

Where really curious to see the answer! Thanks for your help and have fun with the challenge ...

Comment: I don't think your friend came up with that, I've known that puzzle since 2002/2003. I was assured It had an answer but after a long while I was certain it didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible.  Each line has two ends, so you can only have six vertices that have an odd number of lines coming in.  Your diagram has eight.  For a single line, you are asking for an [Eulerian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path), which can only have two odd vertices.